# Charts with swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, charts, core-plot

I'm new in iOS development and want to create an app with some charts. I decided to start development with swift because it seemed to be more easy to learn for me as Java developer. But meanwhile I think using objective-c would have been the better choice because AFAIK there is no chart library available that match my criteria:

- usable with swift
- has line and bar charts
- ability to draw charts with date and time axis
- free to use or low price < 100 USD

Common chart libraries like JBChartView, <s>Core-Plot</s> and iOSPlot do not fulfill my criteria so I'm thinking about either to use a JavaScript chart library in a WebView or switching completely to objective-c

**Is it good practice to use a JavaScript chart API in a WebView? If so, may this make problems on different devices with different screen 
sizes and orientations? What are common pitfalls with this approach?**

Edit:
Core-Plot release-2.0 works well with Swift

Comment: I think it's pretty clunky using JS and  UIWebView - avoid IMHO. What's wrong with core plot?

Comment: @Woodstock Core-Plot seems not be usable with swift because of incompatible datatypes https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments on the linked [Core Plot issue](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/96), you can use Core Plot in Swift as long as you use the code from the `release-2.0` branch. The changes on that branch resolve the issues with `NSDecimal` that 1.x versions of Core Plot have.

Comment: I already tried to use the release-2.0 version and thought there are still problems with NSDecimal in CPTPlotRange.length, but after trying it again it turned out that it works perfectly! So core-plot works great with Swift but this little difficulties has taught me to better switch to Objective-C because it is a more proved technology and especially for me as iOS beginner its important that there is much more documentation available.

Answer (score 10):

You could use iOS-Charts

This is a great chart library written in swift and is on [github](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts):

There are some great tutorials going through the basics [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/).

iOS-Charts seems to fit your criteria

- It is completely free
- It is written specifically for Swift
- It has 8 different graph types

Answer (score 2):

You can use this powerful ios charts library https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

or you can use this SVG library to create your own https://github.com/exyte/Macaw

If you are looking for commercial library (I haven't used this yet) https://www.shinobicontrols.com

This is a great telegram channel, where you can find different useful information about ios development and libraries https://t.me/iostalks